# Unity 3D low fps

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3D 5.3 version. I'm working on a 2D "Endless running" game. It's working normally on PC. But when I compile it to my phone, all of my gameobjects are shaking when they are moving. Gameobjects are in a respawn loop. I'm increasing my Camera's transform position x. So when my camera is in action, all of the other objects look like they are shaking a lot and my game is working slowly on my phone as a result. I tried to play my game at Samsung, on discovery phones. It's working normally on some of them. But even on some Samsung devices it's still shaking. So i don't understand what the problem is. Can you help me with this?

Comment: shows us your profiler charts

Comment: As you progress through the game frame by frame (the button next to the play button), does anything adjust the camera transform values on the PC version?

Comment: No. Just the x value is increasing normally.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is start optimising, if you have a game that is either finished or close to it. If you open the profiler, click "Deep Profile" and then run it in the editor on your PC, you'll get a very detailed breakdown of what is using the most resources within your game. Generally it's something like draw calls or the physics engine doing unnecessary work.

Another thing that might help is to use Time.deltaTime, if you aren't already. If the script that increases the transform doesn't multiply the increase by Time.deltaTime, then you're moving your camera by an amount per frame rather than per second, which means that if you have any framerate drops for any reason, the camera will move a smaller distance and that could be throwing out some of your other calculations. Using Time.deltaTime won't improve your framerate, but it will make your game framerate independant, which is very important.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I'm already using Time.deltaTime also i tried to open new empty project. I just put some environment objects and i compiled it. So, it's still same. Working normally at some phones even old phones. Working abnormal at some phones even new phones.

Comment: What do you mean by "working abnormal", do you mean that the framerate is slower? Because that will be because Android devices come in MANY different shapes and sizes and some of them will simply be less powerful than others.

If, however, you mean the framerate is stable across the devices, but the behaviour is abnormal, then the only thing I can suggest is to try and find any common features across the devices you are using and see if you can make some specific code to handle those cases.